# Correlation Token for Service Fabric Actors and Services

Tags: logging, token, actor, microservices, azure-service-fabric

We started playing with Service Fabric as a microservice platform and after having succesfully implemented our firsts "hello world" samples about actor pattern, stateless/stateful services, web api (and so on) we are moving to looking solutions for other core aspects like auth/autz and application logging.

I have a doubt about the Logging; in all the SOA we have designed till now we always added a "correlation token" to all the services involved (often at architectural level, automatically added as header onto WCF, hidden to the developers) so, now we are trying to do the same with Service Fabric.

Looking for the best solution to let flow a "Correlation Token" through all the actor/service calls, since we haven't found out anything ready out-of-the-box, we are wondering if we are looking for something theoretically wrong.

Any suggestion out there?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of success using [serilog](https://serilog.net) and [seq](https://getseq.net) and using an enricher to add properties to log messages.

In my services I call ServiceLogger.CreateLogger(this) to get the Log enriched with all the state about the service. If you want a correlation token then you should be able to add that relatively easily, but it's not something I've done yet.

I think I've copied the relevant code below!

```
public class ServiceFabricEnricher<T> : ILogEventEnricher where T : ServiceContext
{
    protected T Context { get; }
    private LogEventProperty _nodeName;

    public ServiceFabricEnricher(T context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public virtual void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (_nodeName == null) _nodeName = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("NodeName", Context.NodeContext.NodeName);
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_nodeName);
    }
}


public class ServiceEnricher<T> : ServiceFabricEnricher<T> where T : ServiceContext
{
    private LogEventProperty _serviceName;
    private LogEventProperty _partitionId;
    private LogEventProperty _applicationName;

    public ServiceEnricher(T context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        base.Enrich(logEvent, propertyFactory);

        if (_serviceName == null) _serviceName = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("ServiceName", Context.ServiceName);
        if (_partitionId == null) _partitionId = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("PartitionId", Context.PartitionId);
        if (_applicationName == null) _applicationName = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("ApplicationName", Context.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName);

        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_serviceName);
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_partitionId);
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_applicationName);
    }
}

public static class ServiceFabricLogger
{
    private static ILogger CreaterDefaultLogger()
    {
        var configurationProvider = new FabricConfigurationProvider("SeqConfig");

        var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration();
        if (configurationProvider.HasConfiguration)
        {
            var seqServer = configurationProvider.GetValue("SeqServer");
            loggerConfiguration =
                loggerConfiguration
                .WriteTo.Seq(seqServer, period: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                ;

            var level = configurationProvider.GetValue("MinimumLevel");
            LogEventLevel minimumLevel;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(level) && Enum.TryParse<LogEventLevel>(level, true, out minimumLevel))
            {
                loggerConfiguration = loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Is(minimumLevel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            loggerConfiguration =
                loggerConfiguration
                .MinimumLevel.Error()
                ;
        }

        Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();
        return Log.Logger;
    }

    public static ILogger Logger { get; } = CreaterDefaultLogger();
}

public static class ServiceLogger
{
    public static ILogger CreateLogger(this StatefulServiceBase service) =>
        ServiceFabricLogger.Logger.ForContext(new[] { new StatefulServiceEnricher(service.Context) });

    public static ILogger CreateLogger(this StatelessService service) =>
        ServiceFabricLogger.Logger.ForContext(new[] { new StatelessServiceEnricher(service.Context) });
}
```

Comment: @nick-radell My problem is not about the Log infrastructure modeling, for that purpose my pick is different than yours (I rely on common.loggin + log4net) but it is quite irrelevant.
My problem is **how to let the token flows from clients to servers within the ServiceFabric actors/services**. Even better, if I choice to establish the communication using WCF it's pretty simple, it is enough to add an header via behaviour but the problem is doing the same using the remoting (wich is the default and I would like to stick with it)